# What is the relation between consistency and soundness in mathematical logic?

Tags: logic

Are consistency and soundness the same or some how related in mathematical logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On notation, if $\Gamma$ is a  collection of formulas and $P$ is a formula, then:

- $\Gamma \vdash P$ means that, using the formulas in $\Gamma$, you can use the rules of inference to deduce $P$
- $\Gamma \models P$ means that, in every way to *interpret* logic so that the formulas in $\Gamma$ are true, $P$ is also true
- $\bot$ is a symbol denoting a contradictory proposition

---

*Soundness* is a property that first-order logic has:

> $ \Gamma \vdash P $ implies $\Gamma \models P $

*Inconsistency* is a property that a set of formulas might have.  "$\Gamma$ is inconsistent" means

> $\Gamma \vdash \bot$

A consistent set of formulas is one that is not inconsistent.

Comment: Does soundness only apply to first-order logic or any logical system?

Comment: @K.Smith: AFAIK, you could ask it of any logical system. Generally we're only interested in the ones that do have the property.

Comment: Would you please also tell me the difference between validity and soundness? Because according to the following definition they look the same:  Validity: one cannot arrive at false statements from true statements by applying theorems we know to be true; Soundness: every statement that’s proven is true.

Answer (score 1):

They are two separate concepts. Soundness is used to describe a logical argument, while consistency is used to describe a set of sentences.

A logical argument is sound if and only if the logical argument is valid and the premises are true.

A set of sentences is consistent if and only if it is possible for all the sentences to be true.